# Find Percentage by Sub Group Categories in R

Tags: r

I have a large data frame withe following columns.

For each GEO, and the corresponding Statistics, I need to tabulate the share of that statistics for that DATE by dividing the Value of i.e. NY to the Value of USA, so the final output will be a new column added called share...
So under Share_usa, the first row vacancies share would be 20/1000=0.002,

Then I need to calculate the share by industry total for each geography.  /the share of vacnacy for NY should be 20/40 = 0.5

| REF_DATE | GEO | Statistics | Industry | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 | NY | vacancies | construcion | 20 |
| 2019-01-01 | NY | employment | construcion | 100 |
| 2019-01-01 | NY | vacancies | manufacturing | 20 |
| 2019-01-01 | NY | employment | manufacturing | 100 |
| 2019-01-01 | NY | vacancies | total | 40 |
| 2019-01-01 | NY | employment | toal | 200 |
| 2019-01-01 | FL | vacancies | construcion | 10 |
| 2019-01-01 | FL | employment | construcion | 200 |
| 2019-01-01 | FL | vacancies | total | 10 |
| 2019-01-01 | FL | employment | toal | 200 |
| 2019-01-01 | -- | -- | -- |  |
| 2019-01-01 | -- | -- | -- |  |
| 2019-01-01 | USA | vacancies | total | 1000 |
| 2019-01-01 | USA | employment | toal | 20000 |

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should provide a sample of your data using `dput()` rather than a table. Things will be much easier if "USA" is a separate data frame from the data for individual states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` way. Group by date and statistic and divide all values by the USA value. This means that the USA percentage will be 1.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(REF_DATE, Statistics) %>%
  mutate(SHARE = Value/Value[GEO == "USA"])
## A tibble: 8 x 5
## Groups:   REF_DATE, Statistics [3]
#  REF_DATE   GEO   Statistics Value SHARE
#  <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <int> <dbl>
#1 2019-01-01 NY    vacancies     20   0.2
#2 2019-01-01 NY    employment   100   0.1
#3 2019-01-01 FL    vacancies     10   0.1
#4 2019-01-01 FL    employment   200   0.2
#5 2019-01-01 NA    NA            NA  NA  
#6 2019-01-01 NA    NA            NA  NA  
#7 2019-01-01 USA   vacancies    100   1  
#8 2019-01-01 USA   employment  1000   1
```

---

### Data

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
REF_DATE    GEO     Statistics  Value
2019-01-01  NY  vacancies   20
2019-01-01  NY  employment  100
2019-01-01  FL  vacancies   10
2019-01-01  FL  employment  200
2019-01-01  --  --  --
2019-01-01  --  --  --
2019-01-01  USA     vacancies   100
2019-01-01  USA     employment  1000
", header = TRUE, na.strings = "--")
```